# How do I play a blf file in CANalzyer

Tags: canalyzer

I'm somewhat new to using CANalyzer and have never used the logging feature in the product. I was sent a BLF file to analyze and am unsure how to use it. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: I figured it out. Put CANalyzer in offline mode and load blf into log file. Does anyone know where any good documentation for CANalyer are?

Comment: Just as a side note, in CANoe this is done using a replay block which is added using the "Replay blocks" group of the network nodes.

Answer (score 13):

To be a little more specific:

1. Set the offline mode in the standard toolbar.
2. Click on the **configuration tab**, usually at the bottom of the window. You will see the **Measurement Setup** window.
3. Double click on the **Configuration of the Log Files** block - there you can add your recorded log file (should be in .blf format).

[image]

For more CANalyzer documentation, you can go to: https://kb.vector.com/29/

Answer (score 4):

1. When the `.blf` file is ready, after logging the activity in CANalyzer, open with desired workspace and change the mode to Offline mode.
2. In *"Measurement Setup"* make sure that the mode is *"Offline"* and now right click on the icon which comes as input to Offline block.
3. Click *"Configuration"* and in the next window, remove unwanted file selection and Add your required `.blf` file and press OK.
4. Now press F9 or select the *"Start"* icon on the tool bar.

After these steps, the activity logged will play in the corresponding tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is not replaying the CANoe but it is analyzing the traces from given logs.

For Replaying you need to add this logs into real time ECU running with all configurations