# How to play or open .blf file in canalyzer?

Tags: can-bus

I have to open a .blf file to see the can traces in vector canalyzer. I followed the instruction in

> [How do I play a blf file in CANalzyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635704/how-do-i-play-a-blf-file-in-canalzyer)

But, I am still not able to get the can traces, I tried to search in the vector website as well, couldn't find any instruction, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just dragndrop it into the Trace window of CANalyzer.

Comment: I tried that it doesn't work, do you need a licensed version for that ?

Comment: Do you get a specific status in the write window when you do that? How was the blf recorded? Through the same CANalyzer? CANoe? Was recorded with different service pack? Can you replay it through a replay block (offline mode)?